# Objeto com lista de objetos dentro JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, objetos

Estou utilizando angular para fazer um formulário que contém multiplos checkboxs (utilizando angular-material), esse formulário envia os valores para o controler, que são recebidos da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso pegar esses dados (todos os objetos contém os mesmos campos) e transformar ele em um JSON. Alguém sabe como isso pode ser feito?

Código do meu controller:

```
vm.cadastraGrupo = function (dados){
    vm.disabled = true;
    console.log(dados);
}
```

Meu HTML:

```
<form name="userForm" ng-model="vm.data" ng-submit="vm.cadastraGrupo(vm.data)">
                        <md-input-container class="col-xs-12 md-block">
                            <label>Nome</label>
                            <input ng-model="vm.data.nome_grupo_menu" required="">
                        </md-input-container>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label class="label_tinyMCE left_100">Leitura</label>
                            <md-checkbox aria-label="Select All"
                                         ng-checked="vm.isCheckedLeitura()"
                                         md-indeterminate="vm.isIndeterminateLeitura()"
                                         ng-click="vm.toggleAllLeitura()"> Selecionar tudo
                            </md-checkbox>
                            <div ng-repeat="menus in vm.respostaListaMenusCadastrados">
                                <div style="display: none;">{{vm.data[menus.id_menu].id_menu_rel_permissao = menus.id_menu}}</div>
                                <input type="hidden" ng-model="vm.data[menus.id_menu].id_menu_rel_permissao">
                                <md-checkbox ng-checked="vm.existsLeitura(menus, vm.selectedLeitura)" aria-label="menus {{$index}}" ng-click="vm.toggleLeitura(menus, vm.selectedLeitura)" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="vm.data[menus.id_menu].read_permissao">{{menus.nome_menu_rel}}</md-checkbox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: var conteudoJson = `angular.toJson(variavel);` ?

Comment: Acho que o problema é a numeração que fica, por exemplo, "3":{"id_menu_rel_permissao":"3","read_permissao":true}, teria que tirar aquele primeiro 3, no caso, precisaria transformar aquela variavel para algo como: var batata = [{'id': 3}];

Comment: Esse é o nome da propriedade.Você precisa iterar sobre os itens e transformar, por exemplo, em uma coleção/array.

Comment: Sim, eu pensei em criar um array vazio e ir dando push nele, só que o problema é que eu não tenho o length da variável que eu recebo do HTML e portanto não tenho como saber a hora de parar

Comment: `for(var propriedade in objeto) {};`

Comment: Olá, pode comentar isso como resposta para mim dar como certa, pois essa foi a solução certa. Obrigado

Comment: Bernardo, eu só provi as peças, você implementou a solução. =) Descreva sua implementação, e marque-a como correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a ajuda do OnoSendai, consegui resolver o meu problema da seguinte forma: eu recebo os dados pelo controller normalmente, crio uma variável no formato json e depois faço um loop for que iterege sobre os objetos para salva-los na variável json

```
vm.cadastraGrupo = function (dados){
        var data = 
            [
                {
                    'nome_grupo_menu' : dados.nome_grupo_menu,
                    'authenticator' : '',
                    'permissoes' : []
                }
            ]
        for(var i in dados) {
            data[0].permissoes.push({'read_permissao' : dados[i].read_permissao, 'id_menu_rel_permissao' : dados[i].id_menu_rel_permissao});
        }
}
```